# How to expose non matching rows in LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm unable to return any records where the id does not match between t1 and t2

I've only used a left join, should I be using another type of join for this query

```
SELECT
  t2.service_date,
  t1.some_id,
  t2.service_sub_type,
  t2.subscriber_start_date,
 t2.service_channel_group,
  t1.value AS effort
FROM
   `t1` AS ces
LEFT JOIN
 `t2` AS sts ON t1.some_id = t2.some_id
WHERE
  id IN ('ALK0290907',
    'RUS0290607',
    'RUS0290788',
    'ZAK8461Q001')
 AND customer_start_date > '2018-08-01'
 AND t2.some_id IS NULL
```

I continue to get query returned 0 records

Comment: just remove your WHERE clause to start with! so you will see those "non matching"

Comment: apologies for the confusion (my fault). I was referencing records where the some_id do not match

Comment: don't see any confusion here - you simply eliminates returned result by using WHERE clause. So in another words it is not LEFT JOIN which does not return result but rather WHERE clause which filters them out. so remove WHERE clause to see this

Comment: Can you add some sample data and your expected output to clarify what you want?  You text also doesn't match your SQL, you say id, but your join is on some_id and your where clause has id.  And as we don't know which table id is in, Mikhail could be correct in that it is responsible for filtering out what you want.

Comment: @clintondsm WHERE id should be WHERE some_id. Try removing the customer_start_date condition and see if you get something.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  The query has no table aliases called `t1` or `t2`, and you have not identified the tables where all columns are coming from.